# How to enforce locale inflections on Rails generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, inflector

In Rails 4 (which supports multilingual inflections), I can set:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
```

in my config/application.rb, which allows me to do stuff like this in the console:

```
'general'.pluralize(:es)  => "generales"
```

But when I run:

```
rails g model General conciencia:string atencion:string
```

Rails generates files with 'general' pluralized as 'generals' which in spanish should be 'generales'

Shouldn't Rails be using the multilingual inflector for its generators if the locale is set? Is there a way to force it to use them?

Thanks!

Comment: No one has run into this problem? :(

Comment: I ran, but with the pluralization only, on the views. I had to put the locale on all the method calls. For the scaffold generation, I guess, that may be a big problem, but I think it's a good practice to develop your system in English and translate it to your language, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late, but for the record: There's an argument in a Rails issue about why is it this way (so it's no a bug, but you can discuss it about):

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10125#issuecomment-17274499

> Up to Rails 4, the inflector had no support for multiple locales.
>   There was only one set of rules. The application has a default locale,
>   and in a i18n application each request may have a different locale,
>   but that didn't affect the inflector.
>
> The inflector is not only used by the application, it is also used by
>   the framework to convert paths to class names, class names to tables,
>   create method names dynamically for the associations API, etc.
>
> Obviously, those computations cannot vary. If your schema has a
>   "regions" table, Active Record has to map the Region class always to
>   the "regions" table, no matter the evolution of the application
>   (unless the schema changes, but the schema has to be visualized as
>   mostly static regarding to this, much more static that a configuration
>   option).
>
> I have worked on applications that started development using :en, get
>   i18ned, and then switch to a default locale of :es. The locale is
>   something that affects the interface in that mindset. Everything
>   internal should work as it did before.
>
> You should be able to change the default locale and everything else in
>   a way that does not affect static things like association names,
>   tables, routes, etc.
>
> In could be the case that you have i18n routes (which change with the
>   locale of the request), but in general the statement above should be
>   true.
>
> In order to be as backwards compatible as possible, we have left the
>   framework untouched, and have made the inflections to have a default
>   of :en so that existing applications get the same mappings after an
>   upgrade.